# Jquery Add Selection Numbers Between Brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im finding it very had to add up the numbers in Jquery in selection fields, so far my code looks like this.

```
$(function() {
             $("select").change(function() { updateTotal(); });
             updateTotal();
});


function updateTotal() {
            var newTotal = 0;
            $("select option:selected").each(function() {

                var optionz = $(this).text();

                var newString = optionz.match(/{([^}]*)}/);

                console.log(newString)

                newTotal += newString;
            });
            $("#total").text("Total: " + newTotal);
}
```

The result of this is strange and outputs.

Total: 0{3.25},3.25{0},0{9.95},9.95{0},0{16.95},16.95{0},0{10.25},10.25{0},0{0},0{0},0{0},0{0},0{0},0

[image]

My log looks like this in firefox, i'm guessing I need to output just the numbers.

```
[

"{3.25}"

, 

"3.25"

]

# (line 73)

[

"{0}"

, 

"0"

]
```

Comment: Updated my answer for you to understand the behavior of your `match()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide the `g` flag to `match()`, as stated by [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) :

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the
>   same result as regexp.exec(string).

So, it's the same than using `regexp.exec(string)` (see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)).

The doc then says :

> If the match succeeds, the exec method returns an array and updates
>   properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has
>   **the matched text as the first item**, and **then one item for each
>   capturing parenthesis that matched** containing the text that was
>   captured.

So, just change

```
newTotal += newString;
```

to

```
newTotal += parseFloat(newString[1]); //The string returned by your match()
```

Comment: I am returning numbers, I think it might be to do with the {} being pulled through.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are doing is appending the strings. Instead you want to add numbers, and not append strings.

"3.5" + "," + "3.5" will give you "3.5,3.5"

if you use parseFloat("3.5") + parseFloat("3.5") you get 7, which is what you want.

Comment: Could you explain what I need to change? I tried newTotal +=  parseFloat(newString, "3.5"); and this gave me the value of nun.

Comment: newTotal += parseFloat(newString)

Comment: Tried this also and I get the value of Total: NaN

Comment: newTotal = 0.0 should work, you have to initialize it to a float value.

Comment: I set newTotal to 0.0 and I still get Nan :S.

Comment: I think you have some "," values which you are using for addition. You have to make sure while using parseFloat that the argument is a string. eg. parseFloat("3.5") would work ,but parseFloat("{3.5}") will not work.

Comment: How can i just get the numbers, i tried reg-ex but this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

use this way u ll get the only number

HTmL code :

```
<select>
     <option value="0">choose{0}</option>
     <option value="123">jeroge{123}</option>
     <option value="345">geroge{345}</option>
</select>



$(function() {
             $("select").change(function() { updateTotal(); });
             updateTotal();
});


function updateTotal() {
            var newTotal = 0;
            $("select option:selected").each(function() {

               var optionz = $(this).val();



                console.log(optionz)

                newTotal += optionz;
            });
            $("#total").text("Total: " + newTotal);
}
```